# How do I show that $d:\mathbb{R^2}\times\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a metric defined in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: metric-spaces

If $d(\vec{u},\vec{v}) = \lvert u_1-v_1\lvert+\lvert u_2-v_2\lvert$  for $\vec{u}=(u_1,u_2),\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2)$.

How can I show that $d$ is defined in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Would it be enough to show the limits when $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$ goes toward positive and negative infinity?

Any leads would be appreciated!

Comment: $d$ is defined in $\mathbb{R^2}$ because it's value exists for all $u$ and $v$ you plug in, for $u,v \in \mathbb{R^2}.$  To show it is a metric, literally go through each property we require of a metric and show that it is true for $d.$  For example, show the triangle inequality holds.

Comment: Technically, it *isn't* defined in $\Bbb R^2,$ but rather $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2.$ We still say it is a "metric on $\Bbb R^2$," though. As for how to prove it, take any $\vec u,\vec v\in\Bbb R^2,$ and then show that $|u_1-v_1|+|u_2-v_2|$ is an element of $\Bbb R.$

Comment: To the people who down voted this question; could you please elaborate on what I did wrong so that I can do better next time? Simply downvoting without feedback isn't gonna help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that $d$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2$, because no matter what $u_1,u_2, v_1, v_2$ are, you can calculate $d(u,v)$.

You show that $d$ is a metric by showing that it satisfies all the properties that metrices must satisfy:

1. Show that $d(u, v)\geq 0$ for all $u,v$.
2. Show that $d(u,v)=0 \implies u=v$.
3. Show the triangle inequality.